Language aliases for Stack Exchange sites and Stack Overflow requirements
There are Stack Exchange sites only for a few languages:

Russian
Ukraine
Portugal
Latin
Korean
Chinese
Japan
Italian
German
Esperanto
English

Same for Stack Overflow, only for a few languages:

Japan
Russian
Espaniol
Portugal

Of course, in Area 51, there are some suggestions for more.
But what exactly is needed for a new one in another language? (This question is hypothetical; personally, I'm all for 'Can't We All be Reasonable and Speak English?').
According to Babbel, at least 1.35 billion out of 7.8 billion people speak English (if not more).
If this were only about people/traffic, shouldn't India, with a population of 1.417 billion, have had its own language alias since the beginning? It's one of the most populated countries in the world.
The case of Esperanto and Latin is somewhat understandable, since they are not country related languages.

I'm not actually sure what you asking to discuss here. Area 51 is the place to propose new sites. If you're asking about the process of proposing new sites, that would be better over at [meta.se], not here on Stack Overflow Meta; here is more for specifics about [so] rather than all the communities (or possible ones).

I guess that requiment are atleast similar for exchange and overflow so shouldnt be much diffrent if i asked here or https://meta.stackexchange.com/ and i pointed out both of them

So, can you narrow down and be explicit what your question about [so] is please? Your question appears to aim at other sites in the community, so are you comparing those to [so]?How so? You aren't clear on what about [so] what you to discuss.

It is in question title requirements for language aliase

As I stated, requests for new sites are done on Area 51. If you want to discuss that process, you want [meta.se]. Sites on how to learn, or improve a spoken/written language have nothing to do with [so]. I don't doubt, as well, if you take some time to search you'll find a duplicate candidate over on [meta.se].

@DamianChudobiński: About creation of new sites see that faq on Meta Stack Exchange.

What is a "language alias"? How would it exactly work for Stack Overflow or for the overall Stack Exchange family of sites.

... I'm not quite sure why this question seems so confusing to people. I mean, sure, the terminology isn't quite precise but there seems to be enough information included to surmise what's being requested. While not about SO directly, it seems related enough to SO that it's not totally out of scope here on MSO. Migration to MSE may be better in the end but... meh.

The primary difference between SO variants and SE variants is that SO variants have the entire UI in the language whereas SE variants (with one exception) use English for the UI.
The effort required to translate the UI - and ensure it stays translated - is significant and not something the company is likely to do again. Many requests have been made but as early as 2015 the company clearly stated that no additional SO language sites will be created, even though they were considering how and which languages might be next. That said, this post explains why localized sites are rare and were paused:

Since each new site is an enormous undertaking, our goal with each one is to reach the largest group of developers we're currently not serving as well as we should.
Deciding on the next language is not purely about how many people speak a language. It's more about how many developers speak a language, and aren't likely to be very proficient in English. There are also many technical, and sometimes political complications that we have to consider.

While this statement is quite old, there's no reason to believe they would change that policy at this point and a 2022 discussion on Area 51 was answered by staff with a statement confirming this is the case. At this point, they're not even "working on it" any more.
As far as I'm aware, since the UI is in English, language learning sites still progress through the standard process for site creation in Area 51.
